# Versioning ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I'm using the gem *active_model_serializers* and I'm facing some issues with versioning.

**Controllers**

In `app/controllers/v1/contracts_controller.rb`

```
module V1
    class ContractsController < ApiController

        def index
            @contracts = Contract.all
            render json: @contracts
        end

    end
end
```

In `app/controllers/v2/contracts_controller.rb`

```
module V2
    class ContractsController < ApiController

        def index
            @contracts = Contract.all
            render json: @contracts
        end

    end
end
```

**Serializers**

In `app/serializers/v1/contract_serializer.rb`

```
class ContractSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id
end
```

In `app/serializers/v2/contract_serializer.rb`

```
class ContractSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name
end
```

Whether I call the route `/v1/contracts` or `/v2/contracts`, the rendered json include the contract name, which means that the serializer in v2 seems to be always called.

FYI, I added `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'serializers', '**/')]` in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the serializers in your controllers, e.g. [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485404/how-to-implement-multiple-different-serializers-for-same-model-using-activemodel/13072386?noredirect=1#comment41328063_13072386)